# How to Call Second XIB in IPad at Runtime?

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, xib

In my application i run the video in my first class XIB using MPMoviePlayerController.my video durtion is about 20 seconds.i want that when my video ends its automatically call the Second Class XIB.here is my code.

```
     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
       {
         NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
         NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
         videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
         [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
         videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,768, 1000);  
         [videoPlayer play];
         [self performSelector:@selector(gotonextview)];

         }
      -(void)gotonextview
        {
         secondview *sec=[[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
         [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
         [sec release];

        }
```

This code Give me No Error,but its not call the Second Class after video completion.can any body guide me. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all explained in the docs... also behaviour various between iOS versions.

Do not call gotonextview from viewWillAppear. Instead register your view controller as an observer for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification in viewDidLoad with gotonextview:(NSNotification *)notification as the selector.

Also, I would suggest you launch the movie player from viewDidAppear rather than viewWillAppear.

EDIT: Adapted original posters code (untested)...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotonextview:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotonextview:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,768, 1000);  
    [videoPlayer play];
}

-(void)gotonextview:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *notifDict = notification.userInfo; // Please refer Apple's docs for using information provided in this dictionary

    secondview *sec=[[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
    [sec release];

}
```

Comment: "Do not call gotonextview from viewWillAppear. Instead register your view controller as an observer for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification in viewDidLoad with gotonextview:(NSNotification *)notification as the selector." Make sure you register for those notifications in viewDidLoad NOT viewDidAppear... viewDidAppear is for starting the playback.

Comment: thanx for reply so for.i am unable to understand your methonds can You please edit for me your answer using my code ..thanx

Comment: I have adapted your code and edited my original post. It is untested but should at least put you on the right track. Please read Apple's documentation for more on using MPMoviePlayerController and NSNotification

Comment: thanx @Chris Heyes its works for me well....now i try to increase your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

Use a tabBarController with two tabs. Place your video in one tab and place your "second view" in the second tab. then use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=2;
```

Comment: but that doesn't really answer the question does it.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use a Timer or register an event listener to the video player.

Examples can be found under http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html

Comment: Yes, listen for notifications! but I strongly advice against using a timer.